# Как поменять стрелку в select- html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image: Select]

Как сделать стрелку красной? и разделитель?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть множество способов. Например, делаете свою картинку со стрелкой и бордюром слева и воспроизводите это на `html` и `css`.

Как пример:

```css
.styled-select {
  width: 240px;
  height: 34px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(http://s020.radikal.ru/i721/1511/76/e3954f44bd13.png) no-repeat right #ddd;
  background-size: 10%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
.styled-select select {
  background: transparent;
  width: 268px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 34px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="styled-select">
  <select>
    <option>Here is the first option</option>
    <option>The second option</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/048esrmk/)**

А можно воспользоваться множеством плагинов. Каким угодно на любой вкус, вот к примеру плагин от `jquery`:

http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/
https://code.google.com/p/select-box/

Но проще `css` чтоб не загружать лишним свой проект

Comment: проблемы возникают при margin-left:100px; Почему?  как то странно видится  первый селект с не нужным отступом

Comment: ставлю margin-left: 100px;
    width: 340px; и селект перестает работать- в чем секрет?

Comment: @Stein_ Где ставите конкретно? Пример?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uEj5G/ при огромном выбранном option в селект выбирается он  и  содержимое вылазит на стрелку. а редактирование .styled-select option { width:xxx} не помогает. СПАСИБО заранее

Comment: В вашей ссылке нет селекта. Только два дива. Приведите полный пример кода

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uEj5G/

Comment: @Stein_ Вы издеваетесь?

Comment: Прошу прощения... :( вот https://jsfiddle.net/uEj5G/75/

Comment: @Stein_  Чтобы текст не налазил на стрелку, просто сделайте внутренний отступ справа (`padding-right: 40px;`) у селекта равный ширине картинки, и всё. [ПРИМЕР](https://jsfiddle.net/uEj5G/77/)